# Can't add iCloud entitlement to existing App

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, code-signing, entitlements

I'm having some troubles and none of the posts that I've come across has been able to help me. I have an existing App that hasn't had the need for having iCloud, so I haven't had it enabled. With the next update that I'm making to the App I am allowing the user to be able to load images from iCloud and any document provider that they have on their device. To add this support I am using the UIDocumentMenuViewController class.

In order to added this an it immediately crashed saying that I needed to add the iCloud entitlement to my App. I went to the capabilities tab, enabled iCloud support and now my application refuses to compile. Here are the error messages that I am getting:

```
The app ID "com.mycompany.appname" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.
Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't support the iCloud capability
Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't support the iCloud.com.mycompany.appname iCloud Container
Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier, com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container.identifiers, com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers, and com.apple.developer.icloud-services entitlements.
```

There's a "Try Again" button that re-attempts to generate a provisioning profile but fails each and every time with the same error.

The code signing is managed automatically by Xcode and I have therefore not created an App ID nor a Provisioning Profile manually in my developer account. After reading numerous different forum posts, I attempted to create the App ID manually for use in manually creating the provisioning profile with these iCloud entitlements. I looked in the list of my App IDs in my developer account and "com.mycompany.appname" doesn't show up anywhere. So, I attempted to create a new App ID with the following information:

App ID Description = XC com mycompany appname
App ID Suffix = com.mycompany.appname

The App ID Description is formatted like it is so that Xcode will recognize and be able to use it. When I tried creating the App ID with this information, I got the following error:

```
There were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and re-submit.
An App ID with Identifier 'com.mycompany.appname' is not available. Please enter a different string.
```

I'm out of ideas to try to resolve this issue. Could someone help me out in figuring out why I am unable to add these entitlements to my App, or even as to why this App ID isn't showing up in my developer account.